How to get ttl for each document in mongo
I have set ttl indexing using "expireAfterSeconds", is there a way to get ttl for each document.
P.S: One option is to add ttl and filed expire is set on. Is there a better way out.
How to get remaining TTL for mongo Document :  suggest to do a direct subtraction from "expire_at", but I have created a field based on "created_at" and have a non-zero positive value at "expireAfterSeconds" seconds, Is there a way which mongo provides like in redis "ttl key1".
Thanks,
Sujay

This question is similar to: How to get remaining TTL for mongo Document. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
